# Issue with .setAttribute using cached value

Tags: aframe

I’m having an issue where I am setting a component's data with something like this

```
document.querySelector("#card1")
.setAttribute('card', {assetArray: items.swapper_1,
                       deletedItemNum: nextProps.projects.deletedItemNum,
                       deleteUpdate: true});
```

then in my update function I’m setting the `deleteUpdate` value back to `false`. But, when I come back around to update the component again with something like this

`document.querySelector("#card1").setAttribute('card', "assetArray", items.swapper_1);`

a-frame is using the cached value of deleteUpdate which is `true` because, I'm assuming, I had used it in the previous `.setAttribute`. Then, in my update function, `this.data.deleteUpdate` is now `true` even though I had set it back to `false`. Not sure how to work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you setting `deleteUpdate`? `.setAttribute('card', 'deleteUpdate', false)`?

Or you can just use `this.deleteUpdate = false;` for state variable.

Comment: I was doing both `this.deleteUpdate = false;` and `this.data.deleteUpdate = false;`, but when I would update the component again trying to set a different attribute like the one in the original post it would pass in the previously cached data and set `this.data.deleteUpdate` back to true. I suppose I could've just ran `.setAttribute('card', 'deleteUpdate', false)` after 
 running the code when I set it to true, but I was trying to reduce the amount of times I was firing off the update function. Seems like setting any this.data variables should update the cache as well?

Comment: Nope, you should not be modifying `this.data` directly. We could move that out of the schema and as a component property: `this.deleteUpdate = false`, and always refer to `this.deleteUpdate`. Or update it properly using the `.setAttribute`. You can optimize your `update` handler to diff the changes to do only what you need.

Comment: Ok, I had been setting a `this.deleteUpdate = this.data.deleteUpdate;` at the start of my update function so I wasn't able to just set `this.deleteUpdate`. Sorry if that was confusing. I think the answer was to just run another `.setAttribute('card', 'deleteUpdate', false)` to update the this.data.deleteUpdate like you were saying.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to set this.attrValue.deleteUpdate to false at the end of my update function. I guess the cached values used for .setAttribute are stored there and when you are updating attributes, any undeclared value that you are using will use the cached value as I suspected. I could be wrong on how it's working but that's what it seems like.